# Using a variable as a column name in a SQL statement - python?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to retrieve a boolean state from my database from the column name which is the same as the variable `reward_number` and the userid is the same as `user_id[0]`. However, every time I do this, I get this error:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "1": syntax error

Code:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT ({}) FROM rewards WHERE userId=?".format(reward_number),
                  (user_id[0],))
state = cursor.fetchone[0]
```

Comment: So what more than the error did can we tell you without actual content of data objects and table structures? Print the composed statement, execute it in your database with some IDE (not handwritten code that can require debugging) and check what is wrong with it.

Comment: What is the value of  `reward_number`?

Comment: The value of reward_number is "Reward 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of the value of `reward_number` is `Reward 1` without any additional quotation marks, the database cannot parse your query: it cannot guess that this should be a single token `Reward 1`, not two different tokens `Reward` and `1`, because it has no any external data, just plain sql text. So this leads to parsing error.

To make this work you have two possibilities:

- Avoid identifiers with spaces, which is preferred
- Quote identifiers

[This](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) is how they can be quoted. Unfortunately, it is not described directly and clearly about cases different from keywords, but it works the same. Also you can see that identifiers are case-insensitive regardless if they are quoted or not:

> ```
> create table t
> as
> select 1 as `column name with space`
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select `column name with space`
> from t
> ```
>
> ```
> | column name with space |
> | ---------------------: |
> |                      1 |
> ```

> ```
> select `Column name with space`
> from t
> ```
>
> ```
> | column name with space |
> | ---------------------: |
> |                      1 |
> ```

> ```
> select [column name with space]
> from t
> ```
>
> ```
> | column name with space |
> | ---------------------: |
> |                      1 |
> ```

> ```
> select "Column name with space"
> from t
> ```
>
> ```
> | column name with space |
> | ---------------------: |
> |                      1 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=58795cf31a77e1453434ff943c130e66)*

So the code should be:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT (`{}`) FROM rewards WHERE userId=?".format(reward_number),
                  (user_id[0],))
```